# Coding issue - trying to update single FC using SearchCursor & UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, cursor

Fairly new to python and I have a issue with writing new values to an existing text field in a feature class/shapefile. I want to update the existing text values by taking the Shape@ geometry of the polygon and making a series of text values seperated by a comma.
I got it to work to create the text line and I can write the lines to a file - but now I want to take that text string and replace the values in a field that are already there using UpdateCursor. I want to make sure that all the polygon vertices are written to one filed, then move onto the next polygon as well - here I am trying to compare the OID's - if they change then move on.
I am having issues accomplishing that feat - I can get the values to display in the python window - but then I get a 
"Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 21, in 
TypeError: value #1 - unsupported type: list"

Here is my code so far:

```
import arcpy

infc = "H:\GIST_8125\Oil_Gas\Gail_test\clip_project.shp"

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@", "Coord_stri"]):
  # iterate through polygon parts
  partnum = 0

  for part in row [1]:
  # list polygon part points
    for pnt in part:
        print (str(pnt.X) + ',' + str(pnt.Y))
  partnum += 1

# update coord_string

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc, ["OID@", "Coord_stri"]) as uCursor:
#iterate through rows and update values
  for row in uCursor:
    if row [0] == row [0]:
      row [1] = ([pnt.X, pnt.Y])
      uCursor.updateRow(row)


del uCursor, row
```

---

The first part of the polygon is correctly being written to the field - now just need to find a way to write the 4 other points to the same line:

```
import arcpy

infc = "H:\GIST_8125\Oil_Gas\Gail_test\clip_project.shp"

uCursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@", "Coord_stri"])

for row in uCursor:
  # iterate through polygon parts
  partnum = 0

  for part in row [1]:
  # list polygon part points
    for pnt in part:
        print (str(pnt.X) + ',' + str(pnt.Y))
        row[2] = (str(pnt.X) + ',' + str(pnt.Y))
        uCursor.updateRow(row)

    partnum += 1

del uCursor, row
```

Comment: Your "Coord_stri" field is a text field and can't support a list. Instead of using the list [pnt.X, pnt.Y], convert the list to a string. e.g. `coordlist = [pnt.X, pnt.Y]` `coordstr = ",".join(coordlist)` `row[1] = coordstr`.

Comment: Actually I wonder if a Field Calculator might be a better option in this case. I think the Field Calculator (available in interactive mode or via arcpy) can access the SHAPE@ field and break it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the shape token (`SHAPE@`) to the UpdateCursor and you dont need the SearchCursor:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"H:\GIST_8125\Oil_Gas\Gail_test\clip_project.shp"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['SHAPE@','Coord_stri']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        coords = []
        part = row[0].getPart(0)
        for pnt in part:
            coords.extend([pnt.X, pnt.Y])
        row[1]=', '.join(str(c) for c in coords)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: BERA - thank you SO much for the editing - it works like a charm! All the parts of the polygon are correctly added to the "coord_stri: field as needed. I do have a question though - why only specify the (str(x) for x in coords) - and not mention the y?

Comment: Nice! x is just a variable name, I should have called it something else less confusing. x is in this case each coordinate (both x and y's) in the list called coords. I have changed it to c. Could you accept my answer with the checkbox?

Comment: Thank you for the clarity BERA - good stuff! Checked as requested - this  stack exchange dedicated to Geo is a fantastic resource - could not have done it without you and smiller!

Answer (score 2):

Your "Coord_stri" field is a text field and can't support a list. Instead of using the list `[pnt.X, pnt.Y]`, convert the list to a string. e.g. `coordlist = [pnt.X, pnt.Y]` `coordstr = ",".join(coordlist)` `row[1] = coordstr`.

(You could also combine these statements as below):

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc, ["OID@", "Coord_stri"]) as uCursor:
#iterate through rows and update values
  for row in uCursor:
    if row [0] == row [0]:
      row [1] = ",".join(map(str, [pnt.X, pnt.Y]))  #creates a list from the pnt values, joins the list by comma into a string, uses that string as value for "Coord_stri"
      uCursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks smiller - I think it is so close... when I run in Arc - I get an error:Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found - I think that is coming from the Shape@  geometry as numbers - do I need to covert from float to string in the update cursor... ?

Comment: Yes, I think you're on the right track -- or you could just do this all at once (either with `map` python function, or `row[1] = ",".join([str(pnt.X), str(pnt.Y]))`

Comment: I think this is the one-liner: `row[1] = " ,".join(map(str,[pnt.X, pnt.Y]))`